# Getting started with AMP and RTC as a vendor

Tags: amp-html, double-click, double-click-advertising

I would like to develop and endpoint to support callouts from AMP page as defined in https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-a4a/0.1/callout-vendors.js

### Describe the new feature or change to an existing feature you'd like to see

There is plenty of information about how to implement header-bidding with FastFetch and RTC config from a publisher's perspective. However, it seems pretty hard to find the appropriate documentation for vendors who want to register as compliant in callout-vendors.js

### Describe alternatives you've considered

Can't we add any "Getting Started" documentation for such cases?

### Additional context

It seems that a vendor simply has to register in https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-a4a/0.1/callout-vendors.js (as well as [rtc-documentation.md](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-a4a/rtc-documentation.md) and [rtc-publisher-implementation-guide.md](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-a4a/rtc-publisher-implementation-guide.md))
**Is that correct?**

The integration requires the vendor to set up an endpoint that will be able to receive a GET HTTP request and parse the information that he can define through MACROS or directly from the attributes that are defined in the  tag (e.g: &w=ATTR(width)&h=ATTR(height))
**Is that correct?**

What about **errorReportingUrl** and **disableKeyAppend**?

A proper page for the vendors would be great!
Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Bikemat, same unanswered questions here. Did you find any relevant information ever since ?

Comment: I've try to get AMP organization attention by submitting an issue: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/32064